# How to view files (without changes) of a different branch in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am new to Git, so I am a little confused with this. I have two branches, Master and Test, with a file called Customer.cs.

In Visual Studio tfs, if I made a change to the Customer file in Test branch, the change is only visible in that branch. If I switch to Master I won't see that change. Both the branches are store separately (in different folders).

In Visual Studio Git, even if I switch to master branch and open the file, I still see the same change. Unlike TFS, there are no two different folders for the branches.

Is it how it works in Git or am I not understanding this right? If that is the case, what if I accidentally made changes in the master branch? Do I need to undo all those changes, switch branches, and re-do them there?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to view files (without changes) of a different branch in Git?

Git uses a distributed principle. It will not generate multiple folders for branches in the workspace.

To view files of a different branch, you could use the git checkout command, which a "checkout" is the act of switching between different versions of a target entity.

Simply put, when using git, a temporary storage area will be opened locally to store all our code, and checkout works to switch between versions of code already on the local system.

So, if you accidentally made changes in the master branch, this will not affect your code on the test branch. It is the last submitted code you made on the test branch. Different branches will not affect each other even though they are in the same workspace. This is also the charm of git.

For the principle of git, you only need google git, and you will get more professional and detailed documentation guidelines:

[Git Checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Answer (score 1):

> How to view files (without changes) of a different branch in Git?

The files resides on the same path on multiple branches. Many of the git commands allows for commands like `<branch name> -- <file path>` to operate on only a single file.

E.g. to show the difference of file `a/b.txt` between the `main` branch and the `test` branch:

```
git checkout main
git difftool test -- a/b.txt
```

This will show a side by side view of the two versions of the file. You can also show only the content of the single file in the `test` branch (without checking it out) using this command:

```
git show test:a/b.txt
```

> If that is the case, what if I accidentally made changes in the master branch? Do I need to undo all those changes, switch branches, and re-do them there?

Kind of. But there are tools in git to help you.

First off, you don't need to re-do them manually, instead you get the SHA1 of the commit you added to the wrong branch, then you check out the correct branch and do a cherry-pick specifying the SHA1. Now you have the fix on both branches.

Secondly, you want to remove it from the first branch. If you have not yet pushed it to the remote, then you can remove the commit from the history, using `git reset --hard HEAD~1` (WARNING! this removes the changes made!), this removes the last commit from the current branch. If you have already pushed the commit to the remote, then you can instead add a new commit that undo all the changes in the last commit. git also has tools to do this automatically for you, look at the revert command.